# Java synchronized method around parameter value

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

Consider the following method:

```
public void upsert(int customerId, int somethingElse) {
  // some code which is prone to race conditions    
}
```

I want to protect this method from race conditions, but this can only occur if two threads with the same `customerId` are calling it at the same time. If I make the whole method `synchronized` it will reduce the efficiency and it's not really needed. What I really want is to synchronize it around the `customerId`. Is this possible somehow with Java? Are there any built-in tools for that or I'd need a `Map` of `Integers` to use as locks?

Also feel free to advice if you think I'm doing something wrong here :)

Thanks!

Comment: It certainly *feels* wrong. Perhaps you should edit your question to provide more detail on *why* you need synchronization in the first place.

Comment: upsert sounds like it's executing some database dml. in which case maybe you're trying to fix a transaction isolation problem with locking? if so, that would be a bad idea.

Comment: @NathanHughes I'm using an old version of Postgres where upsert is not available yet :)

Comment: Perhaps I missed the point, but why don't you just do it in a JDBC transaction and let the DBMS take care of locking for you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is called *segmented locking* or *striped locking*. It is too wasteful to have a separate lock for each customer (locks are quite heavyweight). Instead you want to *partition* your customer ID space into a reasonable number of partitions, matching the desired degree of parallelism. Typically 8-16 would be enough, but this depends on the amount of work the method does.

This outlines a simple approach:

```
private final Object[] locks = new Object[8];

synchronized (locks[customerId % locks.length]) {
    ...implementation...
}
```

Comment: Google Guava provide special lock to support striped locking - `com.google.common.util.concurrent.Striped`

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static final Set<Integer> lockedIds = new HashSet<>();

    private void lock(Integer id) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lockedIds) {
            while (!lockedIds.add(id)) {
                lockedIds.wait();
            }
        }
    }

    private void unlock(Integer id) {
        synchronized (lockedIds) {
            lockedIds.remove(id);
            lockedIds.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void upsert(int customerId) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            lock(customerId);

            //Put your code here.
            //For different ids it is executed in parallel.
            //For equal ids it is executed synchronously.

        } finally {
            unlock(customerId);
        }
    }
```

- **id** can be not only an 'Integer' but any class with correctly overridden 'equals' and 'hashCode' methods.
- **try-finally** - is very important - you must guarantee to unlock waiting threads after your operation even if your operation threw exception.
- It will not work if your back-end is distributed across **multiple servers/JVMs**.