# Can I synchronize method by parameter

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Can I synchronize method by parameter?

For example - I get person to some method and I want to do some operation for person, but if few thread call this method for the same person I want to do it one by one.

```
private void dosomething(Long id, Person person) {
    dosomethingelse(id, person);
}
```

How to call dosomethingelse (id, person) only for the same id one by one? but I want that this code for different id-s can be called multithreadly

I wrote this code, but maybe something wrong here or something can be better.

```
public static class LatchByValue <T> {
    public void latch(T value, ConsumerWithException<T> consummer) throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        try {
            CountDownLatch previousLatch = null;
            // we are checking if another thread is already calling this method with the same id
            // if sync has CountDownLatch so another thread is already calling this method 
            // or we put our latch and go on
            while ((previousLatch = sync.putIfAbsent(value, latch)) != null) {
                try {
                    // we are waiting for another thread, we are waiting for all threads that put their latch before our thread
                    previousLatch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            consummer.accept(value);
        } finally {
            latch.countDown();
            sync.remove(value, latch);
        } 
    }
    private ConcurrentHashMap<T, CountDownLatch> sync = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
}
```

Example:

```
LatchByValue<Long> latch = new LatchByValue<>();

private void dosomething(Long id, Person person) {
     latch.latch(
        id,
        currentId -> { dosomethingelse(currentId, person); }
     );
}
```

Comment: I don't think so.  The `CountDownLatch` inside `latch()` is almost certainly used incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, but maybe you know how to do it correctly?

Comment: Do what?  There's already two votes to close your question as unclear. (Neither are mine, I didn't vote.) What are you trying to accomplish?  Please actually explain it, the code is such a mess I have no idea what it is trying to actually do.

Comment: I wouldnt remove the latch, rather, use something that can be increased every time a new thread with same value parameter accesses the method. Working on a solution

Comment: This question is answered here [Java synchronized method around parameter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490900/java-synchronized-method-around-parameter-value).

Answer (score 2):

Problem with using a `CountdownLatch` is that you can't "increment" the count so you need to replace the existing latch when it's been used, which complicates the code.

You could instead use [a `Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) with one permit which would allow you to do the same thing but in a simpler way.

```
Semaphore s = sync.computeIfAbsent(value, x -> new Semaphore(1, true));
s.acquire(); //this blocks and throws InterruptedException, which you need to handle
try {
  consummer.accept(value);
} finally {
  s.release();
}
```

Comment: Make sure that it is not a problem for the sync map to keep increasing in size as more new unique values are used

Answer (score 0):

You can use `synchronized` keyword on the parameter passed (culprit: it cannot be null!). And that also allows you to stop worrying about re-acquiring the lock (it's reentrant).

So the implementation would look like:

```
private void doSomething(Long id, Person person) {
  synchronized (person) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Remember that any other accesses (not in `doSomething` call) also would need to have the synchronization block, e.g.:

```
// another method, unrelated, but does something with 'person'
private void doSomethingElse(Person person, ... /* other arguments */) {
  synchronized (person) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

It would be good document (in `Person`'s javadoc) that the user needs to acquire the lock for that object.

---

If you want to provide a critical section for `<id, person>` tuple, you'd need to change your API a bit - and then pass that object around in your application.

```
private void doSomething(IdAndPerson idAndPerson) {
  synchronized (idAndPerson) {
    // do something
  }
}

class IdAndPerson {
    private final Long id;
    private final Person person;
    // constructor etc.
}
```

Comment: I think it is not suitable for me because I have persons with the same id-s but with different reference. So as far as I understand if I use synchronized(person) or synchronized(idAndPerson) these objects have to have the same reference. But when I take person from db it has new reference even if it has the same id like previous one. So synchronized would be work everytime for the different object

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static final Set<Long> lockedIds = new HashSet<>();

    private void lock(Long id) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lockedIds) {
            while (!lockedIds.add(id)) {
                lockedIds.wait();
            }
        }
    }

    private void unlock(Long id) {
        synchronized (lockedIds) {
            lockedIds.remove(id);
            lockedIds.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void doSomething(Long id) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            lock(id);

            //Put your code here.
            //For different ids it is executed in parallel.
            //For equal ids it is executed synchronously.

        } finally {
            unlock(id);
        }
    }
```

- **id** can be not only an 'Long' but any class with correctly overridden 'equals' and 'hashCode' methods.
- **try-finally** - is very important - you must guarantee to unlock waiting threads after your operation even if your operation threw exception.
- It will not work if your back-end is distributed across **multiple servers/JVMs**.